# Bash terminal stuck in process ([Process Completed])

Tags: bash, terminal

My Bash Terminal is stuck after a bad command.

Even opening new shell instances (cmd T) starts the same hangup ending with a `[Process completed]` message.

It's rendering bash terminal unusable (cannot type or run any other process). How can I kill the hangup process?

Note: `^C`, `^D`, `^Z` do not work.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is on macOS, right?

As it's difficult to edit the file from a terminal (owing to the fact that the shell will immediately exit), open the file you previously modified (probably `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.profile`), from the Finder, in a text editor, and correct the error.

You should be able to toggle the listing of hidden files in any "Open File" dialog box, or in the Finder itself, by pressing <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

Another option is simply to rename the file that you think is causing the issue. Again, do this from the Finder.

---

Speculating on the cause:

You may have inadvertently executed `exit`, possibly unconditionally, or through following some logic branching. Or you may have used `set -e` or `set -o errexit` and then had a utility exit with a non-zero exit status (i.e. failing).

Comment: Might be easier to simply rename the potentially offending file(s) rather than trying to shoehorn them into TextEdit without accidentally making them non-plaintext files.

Comment: @DopeGhoti That's another good option.

Comment: probably calling `exec xyz`

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman That would probably have changed the terminal's tab name, but it still says `-bash` (i.e. it's a `bash` login shell process running).